# Android, Is it possible to run the app from dialer?

Tags: android

I need (if its possible) to add an ability to my project to be run when user enters a code such as #*1234*# in dialer. I'm not sure it is possible. Currently when i lunch my app from application folder it starts but just for fun i want to know can i lunch it with a code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start your application activity class by dialer but for that your app should running in background. for that you should implement a class which extends to BroadcastReceiver. follow this reference code.

```
public class Example extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {

      if (intent.getAction().equals(android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
       String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString( android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER );

         if(phoneNumber.equals("#1234#")) { 
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context , YourActivity.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            context.startActivity(intent1);
       }

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have used this, but it also tries to do an outgoing call after it opens my app. How to make it so it doesn't actually call the number dialed?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by Priyank is right. I just wanted to point out some corrections in the code in the Intent class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){
        String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if(phoneNumber.equals("#1234#")){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this, but it also tries to do an outgoing call after it opens my app. How to make it so it doesn't actually call the number dialed?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if (phoneNumber.equals("#1234#")) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
            setResultData(null);
        }

    }

}
```