# Android Hidden App start from dialer

Tags: android

We can hide the android app from launcher by editing manifest XML,but is there any code snippet or example by which we can hide the app and start it by entering some code like *#*#4444#*#* like that.Any way to do this?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, Is it possible to run the app from dialer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390579/android-is-it-possible-to-run-the-app-from-dialer)

Answer (score 1):

To start your app from dialer you need to do three things:
1. Add receiver to your AdroidManifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.HiddedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

2. Create BroadcastReceiver as stated in xml. It will intercept EVERY calls number. You just need to scan it for your string and do apropiate action - in this case fire off an intent.

```
public class HiddenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        String resultData = getResultData();
        if (resultData != null) {
            if (resultData.contains("YOURCODE")) {
                setResultData(null); // it wont continue calling that number

                //HERE CREATE your intent

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}    
}
```

3. To get this working, you need to tell android you will be using this feature, and to grant [permission to process calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) from the user at install time.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

i didnt test it, but this one works like a charm:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: That was Quick Simple And Easy.. Thnk u bro ;)

Comment: Says Permission only Available to System Apps.. Any Work Around?

Comment: Android version? I was testing it on 2.3.6 &  4.4.2

Comment: I Selected 4.0 Platform the ICS. Do I need To B specific like 2.3.6 or 4.4.2.. won't work on other?

Comment: Sorry! I writed the numbers in steps because there is a third step : _)

Comment: Here's The Manifest     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

Comment: Nope.. But Will Work..  Thank u for Code Brother It was of GreatHelp.. i am probably placing HIddenRecievr class somewhere Wrong main activity code.. will Work Around and get it fixed :) i love That Kinda Stuff :)

Comment: Just place it in e separated file ; )

Comment: Brother That Just WorkedFine... I am going well... But i kept my code as *#4444*#(i consider 4 as my lucky num :P) and i have to press dail button to actually start the app.  Is There any way this can b crunched? Like when v hit *#06# we dnt have to hit the dail button and it gives imei.. So any chance to do like that? Thank you in advanced for the great help :)

Comment: And If kill the app (using Miui) which u know when we hit clear recent task's it literally kills the app.. Then the code isnt working.. What should i do to make it a background runnable like Whastapp or Messenger Does :P Sorry for dummiest questions :P